# LINQ in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a question about usage method in IronPython. Let's say I have some collection and then I create IronPython anonymous type from that collection and I want to iterate all over that collection. My code looks like this:

```
listInt = List[int]([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
firstCollection = listInt.Select(lambda(v): type('SomeType', (object,),{"TypeValue": v*v, "TypeIndex": v})())
enumeratorFirst = IEnumerable[object].GetEnumerator(firstCollection)
while enumeratorFirst.MoveNext():
    item = enumeratorFirst.Current
```

This code works fine. But when I use Select method with index incorporating, then I get error: 'int' object is not iterable. [image: Error]

My code looks like this:

```
listInt = List[int]([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
secondCollection = listInt.Select(lambda(v, i): type('SomeType', (object,), {"TypeValue": v*v, "TypeIndex": i})())
enumeratorSecond = IEnumerable[object].GetEnumerator(secondCollection)
while enumeratorSecond.MoveNext():
    item = enumeratorSecond.Current
```

Can anyone provide me with some help? Why there is error in second case?

P.S.: For interface usage I looked here: [Interface In IronPython.](http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2007-March/004663.html)  For anonymous type usage I looked here: [Anonymous objects in Python.](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/python-anonymous-objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your direct example, i'm curious about the module you're using to create the lists and the IEnumerable (i'm facing a MakeGenericType on non generic type issue), HOWEVER, i managed to reproduce your issue in Python:

```
listInt = [0,1,2,3,4]
secondCollection = map(lambda(v, i): type('SomeType', (object,),
                  {"TypeValue": v*v, "TypeIndex": i})(), listInt)
for item in secondCollection:
    print(item)
```

This throws the same error

> 'int' object is not iterable.

because the lambda is taking 2 parameters, so we only have to enumerate the `listInt` to give an appropriate tuple to the lambda :

```
listInt = [0,1,2,3,4]
secondCollection = map(lambda(v, i): type('SomeType', (object,), 
                  {"TypeValue": v*v, "TypeIndex": i})(), enumerate(listInt))
for item in secondCollection:
    print(item.TypeIndex, item.TypeValue)

>>> (0, 0)
>>> (1, 1)
>>> (2, 4)
>>> (3, 9)
>>> (4, 16)
```

I hope it can help you with the System types, i do prefer Python :-p

Comment: Hi @PRMoureu, I appreciate your help, will try this solution, thanks! Sorry for not mentioning modules that I used. To have an access to .NET types I just imported clr and System, then I added reference to System.Core.dll. To have access to List<T> class I used System.Cllections.Generic namespace. For using Enumerable extensions I imported extensions from System.Linq namespace. Pseudo-code for this looks like this:  import clr, import System, clr.AddReference('System.Core'), clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq), from System.Collections.Generic import *, from System.Linq import *